# I cannot find headers for linux kernel 5.3.10-arch1-1

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, headers

I am trying to modify a live arch linux distro to include some proprietary drivers, but I can't seem to find kernel headers for it. I am trying to compile the bcwc-pcie package for facetime HD cameras. Is there a reason why I can find headers for some kernels but not others? I am relatively new to this kind of thing so sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Download that Linux kernel released tarball and create the package for it. All instructions are here https://www.archlinux.org/packages/testing/x86_64/linux-headers/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arch only supports and distributes the latest version of any given package, including kernels. So you'll have the latest "mainline" linux kernel (5.7.1) and the latest "long-term" linux-lts kernel (5.4.45). Older versions of these packages get purged from repositories, and any other kernel branches are not part of the distribution at all.

The same happened with the 5.3 series – packages for 5.3.10 were removed as soon as packages for 5.3.11 got added. You might still find them on archives, or you'll need to *build* the old package from sources (using makepkg).

(And later, packaging of 5.3.x stopped entirely as soon as 5.4 was released. So even though 5.3.12 up to 5.3.18 were released, they were neither the current mainline branch anymore nor the current LTS branch, so there were no Arch packages for them at all.)

The sources and build scripts for every package remain in the [Git repo](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/log/trunk?h=packages/linux), from which you can build any of those kernel versions together with its -headers package.